# Can someone give me an example of how a low or high pass filter is used in practice?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I understand the theory and math behind electric filtering systems but I don't understand how they can actually be used in circuits. Take an RC low pass filter as an example. For low frequencies, the input voltage will approximately appear over the output terminals but if this voltage is applied or connected to another circuit, then the current/voltage over the output terminals changes as it would if you were using a voltage divider as a voltage source for a circuit.

Comment: @Justme Sounds like an answer there, apart from your questions

Comment: De-bouncing a switch/button through hardware would be one obvious example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An RC low pass filter passes low frequencies and does not pass high frequencies. It is basically a frequency dependent voltage divider, so it has input impedance and output impedance, so it is also sensitive to circuits that drive it or load it.

To have it work you can't put much load on the RC output or it will change the properties. Generally filters are loaded with things that have high impedance inputs so they don't load the filter.